# Massless MS Bar Scheme Self-Energy

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, integration, mathematics, self-energy

In the $\bar{MS}$ scheme, it can be shown that in the massless case, for $\phi^{3}$ theory up to one-loop order, the self-energy is given by:

$$ \Pi(p) = -\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigg[\int_{0}^{1} x(x-1)p^{2} \bigg(1-ln\bigg\{ \frac{x(x-1)p^{2}}{\mu^{2}} \bigg\} \bigg) \bigg] $$

How do we actually evaluate that integral involving $ln$ on the RHS? Wolfram alpha suggests that it should be something complex (the fact it is complex has something to do with the spectral energy density?)

If you just take the indefinite case, then evaluating the integral is easy enough - it's a case of working through by parts $[u=ln(x(x-1)), v'=x(x-1)]$ - however we are left with terms $ \propto ln(x(1-x) $ which are clearly infinite when we take $x=1$...

I think there may be some trick that comes from complex analysis, but I am not sure where.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the $x$ integral by writing

$$\ln\Big(\frac{x(x-1)p^2}{\mu^2}\Big) = \ln(x) + \ln(1-x) + \ln(-p^2/\mu^2)$$

and then using integration by parts to perform the $x$ integral.  You can check your work in *Mathematica* using [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html).